# how to present results of k-mean in R?

Tags: r, cluster-computing, k-means

I have code below like this:

```
act[,-c(1,2)]%>%
  mutate(Cluster = km$cluster) %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  summarise_all("mean")
```

and here is the results.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 12
  Cluster sleep_PersonalActivity PaidWorking Studying Transport UnpaidWorking Socializing
    <int>                  <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
1       1                   10.0       3.84      0        1.19           3.23       0.931
2       2                   11.1       2.07      1.62     1.12           1.43       0.918
3       3                   11.1       0.639     0        0.917          3.43       1.00 
# ... with 5 more variables: CivicReligious <dbl>, Sport <dbl>, ActiveLeisure <dbl>,
#   PassiveLeisure <dbl>, Others <dbl>
```

The data frame has 9 variables:

sleep_PersonalActivity, PaidWorking, Studying, Transport, UnpaidWorking, Socializing, CivicReligious, Sport, ActiveLeisure,PassiveLeisure, Others.

How can I let R shows all variable in result? Do I need adjust tibble size? if so, how should I do? Thanks for all help.

Comment: It is tibble print setting.  If you `View(output)` will see all the columns or convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `print` settings for `tibble`.  We can specify the `width` to `Inf`

```
print(out, width = Inf)
```

where

```
out <- act[,-c(1,2)]%>%
  mutate(Cluster = km$cluster) %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  summarise_all("mean")
```

---

There won't be any issue in `View(out)`ing the output or if we convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`